# How do you access the graphs in Xlythe Calculator App?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, calculator

I have recently downloaded the Xlythe Calculator App ([link to Play Store here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android2.calculator3)). The app claims to support graphing functions. But I have no clue on how to do so. Will anyone help?

Comment: I have  never used this application, but they say, if you want to graph an equation, simply type it in using the basic and advanced panel, then swipe to the graph panel to see it. ( Graphs functions (Y=X^2))

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Ahh, I looked around like you told, and I found out how to do it. Should I post what I found as an answer?

Comment: Sure please go ahead

Answer (score 2):

So, I have been looking around the calculator, and I eventually found out how to graph the functions. I decided to answer my own question, so that it could be a reference for future users. Here's how:

Open the App, and swipe left. You should see this screen:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Notice the **X** there (last line, previous to last symbol)? That's your variable for graphing. The graphs are rendered for `Y=f(X)`, and you must type `f(X)=[insert function here]`.

For example, let's say you want to graph `Y=sin(X)`. Simply type `sin(X)`.

The graph will be rendered as you type. It should be done as you finished:

[image: screenshot]

Tap the graph to get a more interactive graph-based userface.

[image: screenshot]

Keep in mind, this calculator cannot graph implicit functions. Furthermore the graphs aren't gridded. A more advanced calculator would be [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Happy calculating!